# Creating VBA script in excel comparing dates and counts events

Tags: vba, excel

Im trying to create a VBA script for excel  to compare a column of date of format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm .
So I need to print the frequency of the each day occur regardless the time and  calculate the mean of scores of event that happened in each day. The problem that I'm facing is that I have the time in the same cell with the day so I could't compare it with the next day.

For example if I have the following days in column A and scores in column B

```
      A                    B

12/02/2010 13:36           3
13/02/2010 07:36           6
13/02/2010 07:33           4
13/02/2010 09:03           3
13/02/2010 20:04           3 
13/02/2010 22:25           4
14/02/2010 09:02           2
14/02/2010 09:03           5
14/02/2010 10:54           6
14/02/2010 10:54           7
```

I need to print the following days in columns C and  Frequency in D and the mean of scores in column F

```
   C        D      F   

12/02/2010  1      3
13/02/2010  5      4
14/02/2010  4      5
```

Comment: `the problem that Im facing is that I have the time in same cell with day so I could't compare it with the next day` as a starting point, you can use formula `=INT(A1)` which leaves only date (without time): `12/02/2010 13:36` --> `12/02/2010`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to use VBA if you are just trying to get the results of this.

**A formula approach**

The below assumes data is in rows 2 to 100

1. Create a column of the days (you show column C above) (make two then drag down)
2. Use COUNTIFS to get the frequency: in column D2 add then copy down `=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$100,">="&C2,$A$2:$A$100,"<"&C2+1)`
3. Use AVERAGEIFS to get the mean score: in column F2 add then copy down `=AVERAGEIFS($B$2:$B$100,$A$2:$A$100,">="&C2,$A$2:$A$100,"<"&C2+1)`

**A pivot table approach**

1. Add a third column called "Date" or something. Get the date of each datetime using the formula `=Int(A2)`copied down the rows. Make sure your other columns also have headers
2. Add a pivot table covering your data range and click anywhere inside it
3. In the pivot fields drag "Date" to Row header section
4. Drag "Date" to the Values box and right click on one of the value cells in the pivot table and click -> Summarize As > Count.
5. Drag the scores column header to the Values box, and similar to step 4, right click and Summarize As > Average

Comment: I have just  tried the pivot table and it does the work perfectly ! but I still need to do the same procedure  for many  files and I need to do that always  thats  why I need to do Macro .. is it possible to do macro  for this steps of pivot table ?!!?

Comment: @Luara ah i see, yeah VBA is the way to go if you need to repeat it many times. I don;t have time right now to look into it but if you make it clear in your question you need a VBA solution (I know the question mentions a macro, but sometimes people don't realise there is a non-macro way so clarifying it needs to be a macro helps) then hopefully someone else will post something. ;)

Comment: Thank u very much any way .. I found away  using your solution and recording Macro  to do my table and analysis .. so thank u very much ur answer was very helpful.. What Im facing now is a run time error every time I run  this Macro :( ! have no clue whats wrong  but I will ask another question some one might help  hopefully